# JavaScript Variable hoisting without functions

Tags: javascript, variables, hoisting

JavaScript [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope) sates:

> Another unusual thing about variables in JavaScript is that you can refer to a variable declared later, without getting an exception. This concept is known as hoisting; variables in JavaScript are in a sense "hoisted" or lifted to the top of the function or statement. However, variables that aren't initialized yet will return a value of undefined.

Now in my (actually it's a code snippet from W3Schools on the same subject) code I am not using functions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JavaScript index</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    x = 5; // Assign 5 to x

    elem = document.getElementById( "demo" ); // Find an element 
    elem.innerHTML = x;                     // Display x in the element

    var x; // Declare x

    alert( x );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The result of `alert()` is 5. Why isn't it `undefined`. From my understanding the line `var x` should be hoisted to the top and `alert()` should display `undefined`.

I read some more about this from: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-hoisting-explained--net-15092

What am I not getting?

Comment: "var x should be hoisted to the top" --- and then it's initialized with `5`

Comment: What makes you think that the `alert()` would show `undefined`? I don't follow your reasoning.

Comment: _“I am assigning a value to a variable – and then I am wondering that later it has that value …”_ – seriously?

Comment: @CBroe what if OP came from the quantum computers future (to save us from using JS)?

Comment: I was thinking that when hoisting happens with late declarations the initializations were wiped out.

Comment: If you dont understand hoisting in JS, just keep this in mind. `You can use variables, methods even if they are declared at the bottom of your code`. This - hoisting concept does not only exist in just JS, you can do this in basically any language that I know of such as Java, or C/C++.

Comment: @samyismyhero no, that's not so - see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `var x` statement **is** hoisted to the top. Therefore the assignment to `x` happens after it's declared, and **before** the `alert()`.

The sample code in your linked reference that may be throwing you off is this:

```
var myvar = 'my value';

(function() {
  alert(myvar); // undefined
  var myvar = 'local value';
})();
```

That example is different from yours in this essential way: the initialization of the variable involved happens **after** the `alert()`, not before. When a `var` declaration is hoisted, the only part that's hoisted is the declaration itself, not the initialization. That little function above is interpreted as if it were written:

```
var myvar = 'my value';

(function() {
  var myvar;
  alert(myvar); // undefined
  myvar = 'local value';
})();
```

Your code has `x = 5` right up at the top, so it's not the same situation.

Comment: Doesn't the initialization happen before? Your first paragraph states: `Therefore the assignment to x happens after it's declared, and before the alert().` But then you state: `the initialization of the variable involved happens after the alert(), not before.` That kind of throws me off.

Comment: @samyismyhero: Pointy is talking about two different examples. In *your* example the assignment happens before the `alert`, in *his* example the assignment happens after the `alert`. Also note that multiple variable *declarations* don't impact each other. Once a variable is declared, further declarations are ignored. I.e. `var foo = 3; var foo = 5;` is equivalent to `var foo; foo = 3; foo = 5` and `var foo = 3; var foo;` is equivalent to `var foo; foo = 3;`.